# How to get popup without using alert, prompt or confirm?

Tags: xss, javascript

I am trying to exploit an XSS vulnerability, but the strings `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm` are being filtered, so I can not use them. How can I get a pop up?

Comment: Why would you want a popup? You could use `console.log()` or `window.open()` or *any* other function for a proof of concept.

Comment: @Arminius Only guessing, but it is common in training exercises that you need to produce an alert to be able to procede to the next level.

Answer (score 9):

The `alert` function is actually a member of the `window` object. So you can call it using bracket notation like this:

```
window["ale"+"rt"]("XSS")
```

Dividing the name in two and adding it back together with a plus is to make it pass a dumb filter that blocks the string `alert`. Any string operation that results in the string `alert` could be used.